# Can't test iPhone app update as an update

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have been working on an iOS app update and am ready to submit it, however I am having a small issue I am concerned about. I create an ad-Hoc version for testing and when I try to synch the update over to my phone via iTunes it won't give me the 'update' option next to the app. The buttons in iTunes says 'remove'. iTunes actually forces me to first remove the old version of the app and only after it is removed, iTunes gives me the option to install the new version and then the app works fine. The only problem is that this is not really testing the update process and I am concerned that once I release the app to the app store my users will have the same issue where they will not be able to just update the app, they will have to remove the old app first and then install the new version. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS takes care of updating Apps, as far as bundle identifier in your info-plist is the same, any newer version will show as an update in iOS. But in iTunes things work differently. You don't have to worry about these things.

If you want to test effects of updating an App, Install the old version from AppStore. Connect your device and Run the project from Xcode. Now this will work the same way as updating your app.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. when I tried to run it on my phone from Xcode it did not want to update as well giving me an error. I then decided to see if something was wrong with my bundle identifier and saw that there was nothing wrong with it but as I was checking things out I realized that I never changed my version and build values so the update and the old version had the same version and build values. Once I changed those it worked perfectly. It's always the fundamentals that get you at the end.... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem from your part. Maybe this time iTunes is not smart enough to know that your ad-hoc version is an update one or maybe the version of the app on iTunes and on your phone is the same. I've made a lot of update to my apps, when you submit a new one to AppStore your user won't face this problem. They will find an update button for your app :).